# Setting nextFocus to @null doesn't work

Tags: android, focus

I am making a simple activity where the user edits options based on EditTexts, buttons, a list and check boxes. The problem is that the only two EditTexts are top and bottom on the activity, so when you type in the top one, and click the arrow in the bottom right of the keyboard, it takes you all the way to edit the bottom EditText. This feels very counter intuitive and messes with the flow of the activity. I want to make it so when you edit either of the EditTexts, you see the check mark on the keyboard and once you press that it simple removes the keyboard.

I have tried setting of of the nextFocus variants to @null but this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` on the EditTexts. If that doesn't work, try using one of the views in between as the next focus instead of `@null`.

Comment: `imeOptions` worked great. For the record it is `"actionDone"`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can point to itself. Like this:

```
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/carButton"
       android:nextFocusUp="@+id/carButton" ....
```

This will stop focus for up, you would need to add all directions to secure it.